# "Объекты скролятся атомарно"

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css

Доброго времени суток!

В проекте есть поиск по объектам. Объекты идут таблицей ниже поискового поля.
При скроллинге строка таблицы с объектом должа скрываться полностью, а не частично.
Есть ли у вас опыт реализации.

По ссылке скрин с мокапа >> fr35303.tw1.ru/a.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мое мнение: Ищите обработчик на JS, встречал на днях, но к сожалению найти так и не смог:

```
- Если "скролл случился" -> скрольте div на Npx(высота одного объекта)
```

P.S. вот пример, правда немного "глючащий" но база отличная [ТУТ](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/JBAjc/5/)

Comment: Спасибо, Олег!